# angular2 http POST data object issue

Tags: angular

I have been struggling passing an object to web services via http.post using Typescript/angular2.

Below was the path that I tried, but none of them work.

My Component (in TS):

```
export class DataFormComponent {

    newPerson: any;
    errorMessage: any;

    constructor(private _appServices: AppServices){}

    data:any = {"Login":"jsmith","TKID":"4000","FirstName":"john","LastName":"smith","FullName":"Smith, John","Email":"jsmith@gmail.com","ShortTitle":"Library Specialist","Extension":"5000","JobTitle":"Librarian","OfficeFloor":"33","Department":"Library","DepartmentCode":"LIB"};

    saveForm(){
        this._appServices.saveData(this.data)
            .subscribe(
                (result: any) => {
                    this.newPerson = result;
                }, (error) => {
                    // show error message
                    this.errorMessage = <any>error;
                }
            );
    }
}
```

My Typescript Service:

```
saveData(data: any): Observable<any> {
        // let v.s. var, let(block scope) has smaller scope than var(function scope).

        let _url = 'webservices/wsServices.asmx/SaveData';

        let body = JSON.stringify({data});
        alert(body);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(_url, body, options)
            .map(response => <any> response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

My web service:(.Net)

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void SaveData(string dataobject)
        {
            ...
        }
```

The error I always get:

```
Response {_body: "{"Message":"No parameterless constructor defined f…,"ExceptionType":"System.MissingMethodException"}", status: 500, statusText: "Ok",...
```

So I tried to use my old trick. In Angular1, I have been using $.param and JSON.stringify to convert an data object and pass it to my web service.

```
this.saveData = function (oData) {

       var input = $.param({ myDataParam: JSON.stringify(oData) });

       return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'wsServices/wsProcess.asmx/SaveData',
                data: input,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            });
  };
```

I am wondering if there is any similar method/service that I can use for Angular2/Typescript.

Comment: The error comes from the backend code, that can't deserialize the json you post because some class is missing a parameterless constructor. It doesn't have much to do with angular. Error 500 means "Internal server error".

Comment: Thank you. I suspect the client didn't even hit my web service.  I put a stop point on my server site code (web service), but there is no highlight...

Comment: It most probably didn't hit it because the framework isn't even able to deserialize the JSON. You must have some stack trace. Read it. It says that one of the class corresponding to the JSON is missing a parameterless constructor. So fix that. Don't ignore the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  JB Nizet. The issue seems came from my web service.

I changed the parameter type from string to object.  Then it starts working!

```
public void SaveData(object dataobject)
```